# assign the variable with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to assign my variable [vPrenom_id_obtenu] by the value that I get in my MySql DB ...
With the following code, I receive an error message :

> does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteScalar' ....

```
string vFistNam_id_get;
string connDataBaseStr = "server=myserver;user=####;database=myDataBase;port=3306;password=dsdfsdfsdf123;";
string sqlDataBaseSelect = "SELECT column_fistname_id FROM table_identy WHERE column_famillyname='" + vFamillyName + "'";

MySqlConnection connDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connDataBaseStr); 
connDataBase.Open();
vFistNam_id_get = (string)connDataBase.ExecuteScalar();
connDataBase.Close();
```

How can I retrieve the value that is in "column_fistname_id"?
The type of two columns of my table

Le type de deux colonnes de ma table [column_fistname_id] and [column_famillyname] is «text'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecuteScalar is a method to call on an instance of a MySqlCommand not of a MySqlConnection

The right way to go is:

```
using(MySqlConnection connDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connDataBaseStr))
{
   connDataBase.Open(); 
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlDataBaseSelect, connDataBase);
   vFistNam_id_get = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
}
```

However your code is wrong for another reason.

this sql string

```
string sqlDataBaseSelect = "SELECT column_fistname_id FROM table_identy " + 
                           "WHERE column_famillyname='" + vFamillyName + "'";
```

leads the way to [SqlInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

You should rewrite it in this way

```
string sqlDataBaseSelect = "SELECT column_fistname_id FROM table_identy " + 
                           "WHERE column_famillyname=?family";
```

and then before calling ExecuteScalar add a Parameter to the command

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?family", vFamillyName);
```

And as added value you don't have to worry about datatype delimiter (single quote in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MySqlCommand to use ExecuteScalar.  You're also missing the SQL in your source code, i.e. select * from something, or a stored proc name.

```
public static int GetNumRows(String OrchardName) 
{ 
// Create Connection 
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString); 

// Create Command 
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(); 
cmd.Connection = con; 
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orchards WHERE OrchardName = @OrchardName";
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrchardName", OrchardName); 


// Return Count 
con.Open(); 
Int32 NumRows = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
return NumRows; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
MySqlConnection connDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connDataBaseStr);
connDataBase.Open();
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT column_fistname_id FROM table_identy WHERE column_famillyname='" + vFamillyName + "'";
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
string vFistNam_id_get = null;
while (reader.Read())
{   
    vFistNam_id_get = (int)reader["column_fistname_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the ADO.NET types wrong. The easiest thing to do would be to use the MySqlHelper static methods, like this:

```
string vFistNam_id_get = (string)
                    MySqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(dbConnString, "select `col1` from `table1`");
```